# filling a form with parameter already selected using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, dom

My goal untill now is to fill  a form with values from a table (html table).
it is a kind of refreshing the form.
so the user who wants to modify the html table through the form must prefill the form with values wich he already selected.
I used the DOM to acces to each row and cell in the table and i used ajax to pass parameter to other jsp.
but Iam confused what shall be the next step to fill the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the input element from DOM and set its `value` attribute.

```
document.getElementById('inputId').value = 'newValue';
```